# Error creating PipelineModel in Sagemaker

Tags: amazon-web-services, pipeline, amazon-sagemaker

I am trying to deploy an inference pipeline of two models: a sklearn preprocessing model and a Random Forest model.
I have created a pipeline, in which 2 processing steps run successfully producing the 2 models (sklearn processor model & RF model) using my own scripts Then I create a pipelineModel (combining a sequence of both models).

```
from sagemaker.workflow.pipeline_context import PipelineSession
from sagemaker.workflow.model_step import ModelStep
from sagemaker.pipeline import PipelineModel
from sagemaker.model import Model
from sagemaker import image_uris
import datetime

processing_training_image = image_uris.retrieve(
    framework="sklearn",
    region=region,
    version="1.0-1",
    py_version="py3",
    instance_type="ml.c5.xlarge",
)
rf_training_image = image_uris.retrieve(
    framework="sklearn",
    region=region,
    version="0.23-1",
    py_version="py3",
    instance_type="ml.c5.xlarge",
)

# Create a model object with the model artifact and image uri
sklearn_model = Model(
    image_uri = processing_training_image,
    model_data=step_process.properties.ProcessingOutputConfig.Outputs["model"].S3Output.S3Uri,
    sagemaker_session=pipeline_session,
    role=role,
)
rf_model = Model(
    image_uri = rf_training_image,
    model_data=step_train.properties.ProcessingOutputConfig.Outputs["rf_model"].S3Output.S3Uri,
    sagemaker_session=pipeline_session,
    role=role,
)

# Create a pipeline model with a sequence of the 2 models
timestamp_prefix = str(datetime.datetime.now())
model_name = "inference-pipeline-" + timestamp_prefix
pipeline_model = PipelineModel(
    name=model_name, role=role, models=[sklearn_model, rf_model]
)
```

At the last step where I try to deploy the final pipelineModel, an error arises stating "TypeError: Object of type Properties is not JSON serializable"

```
endpoint_name = "inference-pipeline-ep-" + timestamp_prefix
pipeline_model.deploy(initial_instance_count=1, instance_type="ml.c4.xlarge", endpoint_name=endpoint_name)
```

I then tried registering it first before deploying but now it gives the following error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'create_model_package_from_containers'

```
register_model_step_args = pipeline_model.register(
    content_types=["application/json"],
   response_types=["application/json"],
   inference_instances=["ml.t2.medium", "ml.m5.xlarge"],
   transform_instances=["ml.m5.xlarge"],
   model_package_group_name='sipgroup',
)

step_model_registration = ModelStep(
   name="PipelineRegisterModel",
   step_args=register_model_step_args,
)
```

Can't get to the reason of these errors and how could this produce a NoneType if previous steps are running successfully and saving tar.gz models to the designated S3 output paths.. what could possibly be wrong here?

Comment: I would recommend cutting a ticket to AWS support with all the code needed to reproduce the issue